Difficulty simulating prediction interval for quasipoisson GLM in R
I fit a quasi-poisson model (with pretty severe over-dispersion, as I understand it) summarized here:

I'd now like to obtain fitted values and 95% prediction intervals. After some searching, I came across add_pi in the ciTools package. However, when I run add_pi on my model, it produces proper predicted/fitted values but a PI of (0,0):

This is not the case when I run add_ci in the same way - that is, add_ci works perfectly. Then again, my understanding is that the CIs are likely produced using the SE of the model whereas the PIs are simulated. Regardless, I don't know why the simulation isn't working. Thoughts?

Hi @josephfsextion, welcome to CV. This is interesting... personally, I don't understand what a prediction interval would even mean with a quasi-poisson model. Quasi-poisson is not a distribution, it's a way of dealing with overdispersion, by modifying the variance / statistical significance by means of a mean-variance relationship. If you fit a Poisson, or a Negative Binomial, then you should be able to generate a prediction interval. Curious to see what other people think

@AlexJ Your comment should be the answer. Prediction intervals are not defined for quasipoisson models--if OP wants a prediction interval for a count model with overdispersion he needs to switch to negative Binomial (or something else).

Hi @AlexJ and ischmidt - thank you both. I figured this is why ciTools simulates the PIs when provided with a quasipoisson (because they aren't defined). Documentation also states that it provides PI for quasipoisson models: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ciTools/versions/0.6.1/topics/add_pi.glm. And I have the same issue when using this function for a negative binomial model. But if it's defined then I'll just find some other tool (?) for determining the nb PI and forget about the quasipoisson. I had preferred both because I had no preference, but in this case, maybe I do. Thoughts?

Prediction interval doesn't have a meaning with quasi models. Quasi-poisson is not a distribution (i.e. doesn't have a PDF/CDF). Rather, it's a way of dealing with overdispersion, by modifying the variance / statistical significance by means of a mean-variance relationship. If you fit a Poisson, or a Negative Binomial, then you should be able to generate a prediction interval.
